# Jenkins Pipeline Across Multiple Docker Images

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Using a declarative pipeline in Jenkins, how do I run stages across multiple versions of a docker image. I want to execute the following jenkinsfile on python 2.7, 3.5, and 3.6. Below is a pipeline file for building and testing a python project in a docker container

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'python:2.7.14'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'pip install pipenv'
        sh 'pipenv install --dev'
      }
    }

    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'pipenv run pytest --junitxml=TestResults.xml'
      }
    }
  }

  post {
    always {
      junit 'TestResults.xml'
    }
  }
}
```

What is minimal amount of code to make sure the same steps succeed across python 3.5 and 3.6? The hope is that if a test fails, it is evident which version(s) the test fails on.

Or is what I'm asking for not possible for declarative pipelines (eg. scripted pipelines may be what would most elegantly solve this problem)

As a comparison, this is how [Travis CI let's you specify runs across different python version](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/#Specifying-Python-versions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to resort to a scripted pipeline and combine all the stages

```
def pythons = ["2.7.14", "3.5.4", "3.6.2"]

def steps = pythons.collectEntries {
    ["python $it": job(it)]
}

parallel steps

def job(version) {
    return {
        docker.image("python:${version}").inside {
            checkout scm
            sh 'pip install pipenv'
            sh 'pipenv install --dev'
            sh 'pipenv run pytest --junitxml=TestResults.xml'
            junit 'TestResults.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting pipeline looks like

[image]

Ideally we'd be able to break up each job into stages (Setup, Build, Test), but
the UI [<strike>currently doesn't support this</strike>](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38442) ([still not supported](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53162)).

Comment: Are there any updates on this? I have to deal with multiple stages and still looking for a way to do this nicely with a declarative Pipeline...

Comment: No, looks like the issue referenced (JENKINS-38442) is still unresolved.

Comment: I have serious problems with this approach, unfortunately. It seems that the stages are not isolated from each other... With a more complex setup (different stages etc.) I get random lock file error reports  both from Git and from pip-processes. If I create a separate folder for each virtual env, it completely fails (pip tries to install in /usr/local... and crashes with permission errors). Very weird! See my gist: https://gist.github.com/tamasgal/e31c59c56a2c6fdb59adf785617f18c7