# Running multiple Docker containers from a single Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So I spent the whole day trying to figure out how to configure a simple Jenkins Pipeline with multiple Docker images and I am not happy at all.

I need a few stages (prepare, build, test, docs) executed on a couple of different docker containers (currently I just picked three standard Python containers). And it would be nice if those would run in parallel, but I only found this solution, which combines all stages into a single one (and thus creates a not so informative overview in the Blue Ocean UI): [Jenkins Pipeline Across Multiple Docker Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458941/jenkins-pipeline-across-multiple-docker-images)

So I ended up with the configuration below, which is ugly as hell (code repetition everywhere), but more or less creates an good looking overview in the classic UI:

[image: Classic UI stages]

A not so informative overview in the Blue Ocean UI

[image: Blue Ocean stages overview]

And an acceptable test overview from `junit`, which combines all the tests from each stage but if any test is failing, the corresponding "version" is shown:

[image: junit]

The most annoying thing however is, you cannot see which step has failed. If Python 2.7 fails, everything else is also marked as failed and you don't even see which stage failed.

I tried so many different approaches and I am wondering how this should be done. This should be such a common thing to do with Jenkins, so I guess I have some general misunderstandings in this (for me absolutely new) pipeline/nodes/labels/stages/steps/declarative/scripted/groovy/blueocean stuff...

It should be possible to define a list of docker containers some (maybe customisable stages/steps) for each of them and run them in parallel and having it displayed nicely in Blue Ocean and in Classic UI, shouldn't it?

```
node {
    stage("Python 2.7.14") {
        checkout scm
        docker.image('python:2.7.14').inside {  // just a dummy for now
            stage("Prepare") { sh 'python --version' }
            stage("Build") { sh 'ls -al' }
        }
    }
    stage("Python 3.5.4") {
        checkout scm
        docker.image('python:3.5.4').inside {
            stage("Prepare") { sh 'python -m venv venv' }
            stage("Build") {
                sh """
                    . venv/bin/activate
                    make install-dev
                """
            }
            stage('Test') {
                sh """
                    . venv/bin/activate
                    make test
                """
            }
            stage('Docs') {
                sh """
                    . venv/bin/activate
                    make doc-dependencies
                    cd docs
                    make html
                """
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Python 3.6.4") {
        checkout scm
        docker.image('python:3.5.4').inside {
            stage("Prepare") { sh 'python -m venv venv' }
            stage("Build") {
                sh """
                    . venv/bin/activate
                    make install-dev
                """
            }
            stage('Test') {
                sh """
                    . venv/bin/activate
                    make test
                """
            }
            stage('Docs') {
                sh """
                    . venv/bin/activate
                    make doc-dependencies
                    cd docs
                    make html
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update: this is how it looks like in the Blue Ocean UI when a step fails, int this case "Test" in both Python 3.5.4 and 3.6.4 failed but it looks like everything has failed. 
[image: Test step failed]

Also the Python 2.7.14 and 3.5.4 stages are collapsed and cannot be viewed separately. If I click on one of them, all the steps are shown in green although in this case `. venv/bin/activate make test` failed:

[image: Failed test step is shown in green]

Comment: The classic UI cannot show parallel branches. You will always only see the stage name.

Comment: You could refactor your code and avoid too much duplication by storing the commands to execute in variables before the `pipeline` statement (`def buildCommand = "..."`).

Comment: Personally, I recommend that you give up on the visualisation and loop over a defined list of container images that should all execute the build in parallel. This should look pretty compact then code-wise and also execute a bit faster.

Comment: When you say that all is marked in red when some step fails is a) only the case for the classic UI and b) the one stage that actually failed should be in bold.

Comment: So.. your question covers really a few aspect. Still, I think you deserve some help as it is very well prepared in general.

Comment: Regarding code de-duplication: You could probably even store the whole closure containing all the "sub stages" in a variable (so the part directly following the `docker.image().inside`)

Comment: Thanks @StephenKing I will try convert it in a better script to remove code repetition, I just wanted to be sure that this approach is more or less the one which is recommended, before I dive into this Groovy closures. ;) I am simply still confused about the stages/stage/step thing. And the other problem is that I could not find a way to do on the fly modifications of the Jenkinsfile in a multi branch pipeline without having the need to actually commit the changes to the repository. (like modifying the Jenkinsfile directly in the workspace dir of the server). This makes it even more awkward.

Comment: Regarding the failed step visualisation, I don't see the step being bold. Everything is orange and when I click on them I even see green steps, although the Test step failed. I updated the OP... Well, I'll try rescripting in, maybe I find a better combinations of stages and steps ;)

Comment: I was talking about the classic UI regarding the bold stage. Interesting that all are orange, you're right.. that's stupid I would say.

Comment: Instead of storing the closure I would actually loop over a list of containers and define the build steps once. And I recommend to do them in parallel as this safes you time. Maybe [this slide deck of mine, slide 44ff](https://www.slideshare.net/StephenKing/declarative-jenkins-pipelines) provides you with some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for your slide deck @StephenKing it looks very informative. I'll walk through it. Currently I am trying to figure out how to use variable names in the docker image (it doesn't work this way: https://gist.github.com/tamasgal/a05afafbf696d202d694f94f78317f80)

Answer (score 8):

*So this is what I ended up with. There are surely better solutions, but I have to move on. I hope to gather some (better) answers in time, I'll not mark this as "the solution" yet ;)*

First, some credits to Stephen Kings slides (the title says "Declarative" but there are some nice examples regarding the scripted Pipeline): [(Declarative) Jenkins Pipelines](https://www.slideshare.net/StephenKing/declarative-jenkins-pipelines)

Here is my [gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/tamasgal/a05afafbf696d202d694f94f78317f80) with the following snippet:

```
def docker_images = ["python:2.7.14", "python:3.5.4", "python:3.6.2"]

def get_stages(docker_image) {
    stages = {
        docker.image(docker_image).inside {
            stage("${docker_image}") {
                echo 'Running in ${docker_image}'
            }
            stage("Stage A") {
                switch (docker_image) {
                    case "python:2.7.14":
                        sh 'exit 123'  // for python 2.7.14 we force an error for fun
                        break
                    default:
                        sh 'sleep 10'  // for any other docker image, we sleep 10s
                }
                sh 'echo this is stage A'  // this is executed for all
            }
            stage("Stage B") {
                sh 'sleep 5'
                sh 'echo this is stage B'
            }
            stage("Stage C") {
                sh 'sleep 8'
                sh 'echo this is stage C'
            }

        }
    }
    return stages
}

node('master') {
    def stages = [:]

    for (int i = 0; i < docker_images.size(); i++) {
        def docker_image = docker_images[i]
        stages[docker_image] = get_stages(docker_image)
    }

    parallel stages
}
```

I tried to make it easy to use:

- you add your Docker images in a list at the top and then you define the `stages` in the `get_stages()` function
- add the common stages and steps
- if any Docker image needs special treatment (like `python:2.7.14` in my example), you can use a simple `switch`. This could also be realised with a double map for the special cases ('images'->'stage'='steps') and a fallback double map for defaults, but I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader. (to be honest, I could not figure out the correct, supported Groovy-lang syntax)

This is how it looks like when everything is fine in both the Classic and the Blue Ocean UIs (it's known that the Blue Ocean UI fails to display multiple stages in parallel runs, see [JENKINS-38442](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38442?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel)):

**Classic UI**
[image: Classic UI - Build OK]

**Blue Ocean UI**
[image: Blue Ocean UI - Build OK]

And this is the output if `Stage A` in `python:2.7.14` fails:

**Classic UI**
[image: Classic UI - Failed Stage A step]

**Blue Ocean UI**
[image: Blue Ocean UI - Failed Stage A step]

Comment: what can I do if my tests needs MySQL ?

Comment: @HappyCoder you can provide your own Dockerfile where mysql will be installed during the container setup